# How to get current time in Scala in timestamp/datetime format so that it can be stored in PG table

Tags: java, scala, datetime, timestamp, jodatime

I have written the following function in Scala which works:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Calendar, Date}
import java.util.{TimeZone, Date}


val curr_timeFmt = "YYYY_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"

def curr_time(): String = {
    val date = new Date
    val currTS = new SimpleDateFormat(curr_timeFmt)
    currTS.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    currTS.format(date)
  }
```

I would like to store the return value from this function as a timestamp in a PG columnn of type timestamp.

Furthermore, while researching online, I heard that the the Java Calendar and Date classes are not thread safe and mutable. Is this true, if so how can I use the new joda time in Java 8?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as Ive been looking online for a while and tried a few things and nothing seemed to work.

Thx

Comment: *"how can I use the new joda time in Java 8?"* [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) predates Java 8, and was actually the baseline for the new Java Time API in Java 8. Joda-Time has been deprecated in favor of the new Java Time API.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `TimeZone` and `Calendar`. Those classes are all poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter`, `LocalDateTime`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the current time in US Eastern time zone, in that format, using [Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

```
val fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")
val time = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(fmt)
```

Printing value of `time` shows e.g.

```
2019_03_18_21_32_22
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of using Joda in scala

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat 
LocalDateTime.now.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"))
```